# How to convert a datetime.time type to float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am performing a data analysis with python. I need to convert a data type from datatime.time to float, something like what makes Excel when we change the cell format from "time" to "number".

[image]

I could load the data on excel, change the columns format, export them again to CSV and finally load again into a dataframe, but I don't want to perform all that process again.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: **How** do you want to convert it to float? Do you want the representation of time as seconds from the epoch? As the fraction of the day that has passed? Or what?

Comment: Also: which day? synodic day? Sidereal day?

Comment: @Bakuriu it seems clear from the question that they want the same decimal number that Excel displays, however it calculates it.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal number used by Excel is simply the fraction of a day that a time represents, with midnight being 0.0.  You simply take the hours, minutes, and seconds in the time and divide by the fraction of a day they represent:

```
def excel_time(time):
    return time.hour / 24.0 + time.minute / (24.0*60.0) + time.second / (24.0*60.0*60.0) + time.microsecond / (24.0*60.0*60.0*1000000.0)
```